# How do I grep file paths out of a text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a file that has a list of paths like so:

```
"1"       "/user/bin/share"
"2"       "/home/user/.local"
"3"       "/root/"
```

Is there a way to extract *just* the paths? I dont want the numbers or quotation marks. How can I sed or grep the paths out of the file? What regex would be required for such a task?

Comment: you can use `sed -r 's/.*"(.*)"$/\1/'` as answered to your [newly duplicated question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/467427/72456).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the paths start with `/`, you could just match `/` followed by a sequence of non-`"` characters:

```
$ grep -o '/[^"]*' file
/user/bin/share
/home/user/.local
/root/
```

Alternatively, for a more structured approach, use `awk` to strip quotes from and print just the second field:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2}' file
```

Comment: `awk` solution would not work if there was a whitespaces in `path`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the paths do not contain newline characters,

```
$ sed 's/^.*[[:blank:]]"//; s/"$//' <file
/user/bin/share
/home/user/.local
/root/
```

The `sed` code first removes everything on each line up to and including the first `"` character preceded by a blank (space or tab). It then removes the `"` at the end.

This allows the paths to contain spaces and embedded `"` characters, but not the combination blank+`"`.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't a simple

```
awk -F\" '{print $4}' file
/user/bin/share
/home/user/.local
/root/
```

work?

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach.  Pluck out field #4, with quotes as delimiters, using `cut`.

```
$ cut -f4 -d\" file
/user/bin/share
/home/user/.local
/root/
$
```