# How to extract path names from a log file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

This is similar to eg [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467412/how-do-i-grep-file-paths-out-of-a-text-file) , but not quite; I have the output from strace saved into a file, like this:

```
...
3691  fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                 = 0
3691  access("/etc/suid-debug", F_OK)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3691  access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
3691  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
3691  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=243756, ...}) = 0
3691  mmap(NULL, 243756, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff0696c2000
3691  close(3)                          = 0
3691  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
3691  read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
3691  fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3076960, ...}) = 0
...
```

Is there an easy way to print out only the paths, which in this case don't seem to be easy to parse with awk?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a combination of grep and sed:

```
 ... | grep '"/' | sed 's/^.*"\(/[^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

That may have a few false positives from data strings that happen to start with a slash, and maybe also fail for pathnames containing a literal double-quote, and it would not find a second path in one line, but it's a start...

You could also grep for "openat" and other syscalls with path arguments:

```
 ... | grep -e openat -e access | sed ...
```

to further reduce false positives.

Comment: Why the `grep`? Wouldn't just `sed -rn 's|^.*"(/[^"]*)".*$|\1|p'` do?

Comment: Legit question ;-)   Answer: I wasn't familiar with the "p"-flag.   Anyway, I'd still recommend the grep for pre-selecting relevant system calls from the dump.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"(\/[^"]+)/,a){print a[1]}' file
/etc/suid-debug
/etc/ld.so.preload
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

otherwise using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/"\/[^"]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' file
/etc/suid-debug
/etc/ld.so.preload
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
grep -Po '(\(|, )"\K/[^"]*'
```

to find the sequences of non-`"` characters starting with `/` that follow either `("` or `, "`.

This may even be enough:

```
grep -Po '"\K/[^"]*'
```

for the sequences of non-`"` characters starting with `/` that follow a `"`.

They will only report absolute paths (the ones starting with `/`). They may report things that are not meant to be paths such as in `write("// some C++ comment", ...)` and the latter could be fooled by things like `write("foo \"/bar\" baz"...)`.

For a stricter matching that allows relative paths, you'd need to cover all the syscalls that take path arguments in your regexp. From your sample:

```
grep -Po '^\d+\s+((open|access)\(|openat\(\S+, )"\K(\\.|[^"])*'
```

To exclude the paths from failing syscalls, you could append `(?!.*\) = -1)` (a negative look-ahead assertion) to your regexp. See also the `-z` / `--successful-only` / `-e status=successful` `strace` options, and the `-e trace=%file` to only trace file-related system calls.